# Else If block and curly brackets

Tags: php, if-statement

Knowing that in PHP we could ignore curly brackets in conditional blocks with only one function / line after the "if", "else if" or "else" tag, like this :

```
if (myVal == "1")
  doThis();
else if (myVal == "2")
  doThat();
else
  doNothing();
```

I was asking myself if something like this :

```
 if (myVal == "1")
  doThis();
else 
  if (myVal2 == true)
    doThat();
  else
    doNothing();
```

Was seen by PHP as either this :

```
if (myVal == "1")
{ doThis(); }
else 
{
  if (myVal2 == true)
    { doThat(); }
  else 
    { doNothing(); }
}
```

or this :

```
if (myVal == "1")
  { doThis(); }
else if(myVal2 == true)
  { doThat(); }
else 
  { doNothing(); }
```

**Short version :** Is the "line break" after one else enough to separate it from one "if" statement or will it be seen as one "else if"

---

Editing my own question to get a confirmation about my guess :

```
if(false)
  echo "1";
else 
  if (false)
    echo "2";
else
  echo "3";
```

Is displaying "3" while the following is throwing an error because two else statement were found :

```
if(false)
  echo "1";
else 
  if (false)
    echo "2";
  else
    echo "4";
else
  echo "3";
```

So the break line doesn't seems to make any difference, the only thing that matters is the "if" and "else" count.

Comment: Obvious question: Have you tried it? It should be fairly easy to test it for yourself. However, I feel I should make a stand and say that regardless of whether PHP *allows* you to drop the brackets, good programming practice would be to always include them, even in cases where they are optional. There really is no good reason at all to drop them, and plenty of reasons why it's a bad idea.

Comment: also, don't forget that PHP has an `elseif()`. If you use that, it would remove any doubt from the question.

Comment: @Spudley Indeed, brackets should always be present. I'll try to find a situation where I could test this quickly, will post the results if nobody got them before. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the curly brackets PHP will treat only the next line as the block of code to execute.

```
if (myVal == "1")
    doThis();
else 
    if (myVal2 == true)
    doThat();
    else
    doNothing();
```

If `myVal` is `"1"` `doThis();` is the next line and is thus picked as the block of code to execute. If there was more code there:

```
if (myVal == "1")
    doThis();
    doThisToo();
```

It would still execute only `doThis()` as part of the `if` statement, whilst `doThisToo()` would **always** be executed.

If `myVal != "1"` it picks the first block in the `else` condition and executes only that.
In this case it is another `if` statement that needs to be evaluated:

```
if (myVal2 == true)
```

This logic continues: Identify the next block of code to execute by either taking the next line or the next block identified by a wrapping of curly braces.

Comment: Then if PHP is picking only the first block in the first else condition, supposing `myVal != "1"` and `myval2 == false`, would the `doNothing()` function be done ? Thanks

Comment: Evaluates (myVal == 1) as false, jumps into next else condition. first line is next block. Evaluates (myVal2 == 2) as false, jumps into next else, identifies first block as next line, executes doNothing()

Answer (score 0):

I think that both of your example results do **exactly the same**.

`else` always belongs to the preceding `if` unless curly braces specify it otherwise.

`if` (including the optional `else` and their subsequent statements as single-statement or curly-braces wrapped block)  is always treated as a sigle statement itself, so

```
{
    if(...) {} else {}
}
```

is in fact the same as

```
if(...) {} else {}
```